# How to write a block, conflict with block call and passing arguments to methods

Tags: ruby

I am trying to learn blocks but I am not able to run the below code after verifying the syntax:

```
class Test
  def arthmatic(a=5,b=6)
    yield(a,b)
  end

  arthmatic do |a,b|
    if a > b
      puts "x is greater"
    else 
      puts "y is greater"
    end
  end
end

test.new.arthmatic(6, 7)
```

Comment: It'd help if you'd indent your code. By doing so you can more quickly locate problems with logic.

Comment: @thinkingmonster I left a suggested edit on your question where I styled the code to be more idiomatic Ruby. Of course, you're under no compulsion to format your code like most everyone else, but in general I think it's a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error:

```
test.rb:7: undefined method `arthmatic' for Test:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Your syntax is ok, but you are trying to call arthmatic from a wrong scope (the class scope of Test)

You need to do this:

```
class Test
    def arthmatic(a=5,b=6)
        yield(a,b)
    end

    Test.new.arthmatic {|a,b|

    if a > b

    then
    puts "x is greater"
    else
    puts "y is greater"
end
}
end

Test.new.arthmatic(6, 7) do |a,b|
  puts a,b 
end
```

Or this

```
class Test
    def self.arthmatic(a=5,b=6) # class method
        yield(a,b)
    end

    arthmatic {|a,b|

    if a > b

    then
    puts "x is greater"
    else
    puts "y is greater"
end
}
end

Test.arthmatic(6, 7) do |a,b|
    puts a, b
end
```

That was regarding method scope, also you forget to pass the block in the last method call, you need to fix by checking the block on the method:

```
    def self.arthmatic(a=5,b=6) # class method
        yield(a,b) if block_given?
    end
```

Or by always passing it

```
Test.arthmatic(6, 7) do |a,b|
    puts a, b
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You supply the block to the method when you call it, not in the class, so try this:

```
class Test
  def arthmatic(a=5,b=6)
    yield(a,b)
  end
end

Test.new.arthmatic(6, 7) do |a, b|
  if a > b
    puts "x is greater"
  else 
    puts "y is greater"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

in Ruby, we don't normally use if..then... rather, just if ... else... end.

```
if
   do something
else
   do something different
end
```

Also, blocks of code (if more then one line) normally start with "do" and finish with "end":

```
do
  ..something..
end
```

blocks of code, if passed to a method, should be passed as part of the method call, usually after the arguments (this is design dependent, sometimes the block will be the last argument, but it will always be part of the method call)...

Also, Ruby is case sensitive. you called test.new when you wanted Test.new.

The final code will look like:

```
class Test
  def arthmatic(a=5,b=6)
    yield(a,b)
  end
end

Test.new.arthmatic(6, 7) do |a,b|
  if a > b
  then 
    puts "x is greater"
 else 
    puts "y is greater"
  end
end
```

Good luck!